# avoid two odd pages one roman and another arabic

Tags: page-numbering, double-sided, arabic, roman-numerals

I have a two-sided thesis, and tables of contents page numbering is roman and the chapter 1 starts with arabic page numbering.

I set higher margin for odd pages, but I dealt with two pages in a row with odd and long margin. I know that `\pagenumbering{arabic}` always sets the first page odd, however I want to make it flexible to be odd or even depending on the size of the table of contents.

Please help me in this case. Thank you.

Comment: it's usual for the first real chapter of a book or report to start on a right-hand (odd) page, and theses typically follow one of those styles.  so it might make more sense to add a blank page, if necessary, between the contents page and the start of the main body.  that's what `\mainmatter` does in many book-format document classes (in addition to changing page numbers to arabic).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also solved it by "manually" putting one blank page at the end of table of contents (TOC). However, this requires the knowledge of TOC size in advance. I wish there was a latex trick or command to "automatically" solve this problem.

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` should do what is needed -- if the toc ends on a left-hand page, it simply goes to the next right-hand page, but if the toc ends on a right-hand page, it adds a blank.

Comment: The problem with \cleardoublepage is that it forces all chapters to start from the odd page, and as a result 50% chance of blank page before each chapter. I personally don't want to see any empty pages there.

Comment: no, i wasn't suggesting to do it everywhere, just immediately after the toc.

Comment: Actually my thesis has Acknowledgment after toc. So, after putting \cleardoublepage after Acknowledgement and before \chapter{First}, what happened was that Acknowledgement got arabic page number 1 while I was expecting it to be roman (xli). I wanted to see page number 1 for the Chapter first which was immediately after \mainmatter. Anyways, it seems that the more work I do on the latex code the worse result do I get. So, I stuck with the old idea of manually adding a page before \chapter{First}. Thank you for your answers.